# Weird behaviour on singleton class

Tags: java, android, singleton

I've build a singleton class to check if I am online before performing an external database upload.

To do so, this is the class:

```
public class InternetConnection
{
    private static InternetConnection instance = null;

    public static InternetConnection getInstance()
    {
        if(instance == null)
        {
            instance = new InternetConnection();
        }

        return instance;
    }


    private InternetConnection()
    {

    }

    public boolean isOnline(Context context)
    {

        ConnectivityManager connMgr = (ConnectivityManager)context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo networkInfo = connMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        return (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected());

    }
}
```

Outside, on an Activity, I call it like so:

```
if (InternetConnection.getInstance().isOnline(this)) {
  //I am online, so I upload to my external database
} else {
  // I am not online
}
```

However, when it enters in getInstance() method, it evaluates `instance == null` ( which when I debug is true ) but, instead of entering in true branch and performing instance = new InternetConnection() it skips this branck and returns null, which causes a null object exception outside.

Why is this happening? How is possible that if `instance == null` is true it skips the branch for true case?

Thanks!

Comment: can you please share log file

Comment: try cleaning project

Comment: It works fine for me, try cleaning and building the project again. let us know if the problem persists after that

Comment: +1 as everyone has mentioned that it works... if you want to look further http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37397014/implementing-the-singleton-pattern-for-accessing-an-object-anywhere/37398014#37398014

Comment: You are right, cleaning project worked! Thank you very much!

Comment: Are you using multithreading? may be you need to use synchronized on getInstance function?